# Mockito how can simule record doesn't exist

Tags: mockito

.exception.INSSTaxNotFoundException: INSS Tax not found with ID 1
Could someone help me?
I want mokite "inssTaxService.findById", I don't know how do.
I get this error: INSSTaxNotFoundException: INSS Tax not found with ID 1.
But I could like found the record and go on.

Can I do that in Service or Not?

```
@Test
void whenINSSTaxIdInformedThenReturnThisINSSTax() throws INSSTaxNotFoundException {

        INSSTaxDTO expectedSavedInssTaxDTO = INSSTaxBuilder.builder().build().toINSSTaxDTO();
        INSSTax expectedSavedInssTax  = inssTaxMapper.toModel(expectedSavedInssTaxDTO);
        
        when(inssTaxService.findById(expectedSavedInssTaxDTO.getId())).
                thenReturn(expectedSavedInssTaxDTO);
        
        assertEquals(expectedSavedInssTax.getId(), expectedSavedInssTaxDTO.getId());
        assertEquals(expectedSavedInssTax.getDescription(), expectedSavedInssTaxDTO.getDescription());
        assertEquals(expectedSavedInssTax.getSocialSecurityRatePercent(), expectedSavedInssTaxDTO.getSocialSecurityRatePercent());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might be missing is actually injecting the mock of `inssTaxService` inside your class which you are testing,

Your code would be something like this. 
Considering its a pure java code(not spring boot etc, you can change the code accordingly in that case).

Mock the service(Which i feel you have done else Mockito would have thrown and error)

```
InssTaxService mockedInssTaxService = Mockito.mock(InssTaxService.class);
//other impl on this mock for this e.g 
when(mockedInssTaxService.findById(expectedSavedInssTaxDTO.getId())).
                thenReturn(expectedSavedInssTaxDTO);
```

Inject the mocked object to the `ClassToTest`.

```
ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(mockedInssTaxService);
```

If you are using spring boot test you can use `@MockBean` or `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` instead of new keyword